# Regular Expression to not allow disposable email addresses

Tags: regex, validation, expression

I'm trying to create a regex that does not allow disposable email addresses but allows everything else. So far, here is what I have:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(((?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))(?=.*(?!.*mailinator.com))(?=.*(?!.*trbvm.com))(?=.*(?!.*guerrillamail.com))(?=.*(?!.*guerrillamailblock.com))(?=.*(?!.*sharklasers.com))(?=.*(?!.*guerrillamail.net))(?=.*(?!.*guerrillamail.org))(?=.*(?!.*guerrillamail.biz))(?=.*(?!.*spam4.me|grr.la))(?=.*(?!.*guerrillamail.de))(?=.*(?!.*grandmasmail.com))(?=.*(?!.*zetmail.com))(?=.*(?!.*vomoto.com))(?=.*(?!.*abyssmail.com))(?=.*(?!.*anappthat.com))(?=.*(?!.*eelmail.com))(?=.*(?!.*yopmail.com))(?=.*(?!.*fakeinbox.com)))$
```

Right now, it accepts all email addresses.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Thanks, am I able to ask them separately through a model on an MVC site though? Or would this all have to be server side?

Answer (score 1):

Try this slightly modified regex using lookbehind:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(((?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))(?<!mailinator\.com)(?<!trbvm\.com)(?<!guerrillamail\.com)(?<!guerrillamailblock\.com)(?<!sharklasers\.com)(?<!guerrillamail\.net)(?<!guerrillamail\.org)(?<!guerrillamail\.biz)(?<!spam4\.me)(?<!grr\.la)(?<!guerrillamail\.de)(?<!grandmasmail\.com)(?<!zetmail\.com)(?<!vomoto\.com)(?<!abyssmail\.com)(?<!anappthat\.com)(?<!eelmail\.com)(?<!yopmail\.com)(?<!fakeinbox\.com))$
```

It matches `bob@gmail.com` but does not match `bob@mailinator.com`.

Fundamentally, you had a regex to match any email address, followed by positive and negative lookaheads like `(?=.*(?!.*mailinator.com))`. By the time those lookaheads are executed, you're already at the end of the string (further enforced by the `$`).

Looking **ahead** from the end of the string there is… nothing. Any lookahead (positive or negative) into nothingness will either always pass, or always fail, regardless of the input string. E.g. a lookahead of `(?=.*)` at the end of a string will always pass (`.*` matches the empty string), whereas one of `(?=.)` will always fail (`.` does not match the empty string).

In your case, the lookaheads like `(?=.*(?!.*mailinator.com))` are okay with the nothingness beyond the end of the input string, so always pass. It's identical to if you didn't have them in the regex at all.

The simple fix, without overhauling the regex entirely, is to look **behind** with the `(?<!)` construct, instead of ahead. You're at the end of the string, and want to ensure it didn't end with one of the disposable email domains you have listed. To do that for one domain, it would be `(?<!mailinator\.com)`.